# react state not updating with togglepress

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to toggle the info window in react-google-maps off and on through a custom component. The toggle method is being called as I checked if it's logged. Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Created by.
 */
import * as React from 'react'
import {Col, Row, Card, CardHeader, CardBody, CardColumns, CardText, CardFooter} from 'reactstrap'
import {InfoWindow, Marker} from 'react-google-maps'

export default class home extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isOpen: false
    }

    toggleOpen = () => {
        this.setState(({ isOpen }) => (
            {
                isOpen: !isOpen,
            }
        ));
        if(this.state.isOpen)
            console.log("state is open")
        else
            console.log("state is not open")
    }



    render()
    {
        const { isOpen } = this.state;
        return (
            <Marker
                position={this.props.position}
                onClick={this.toggleOpen}>
                <InfoWindow isOpen={isOpen}>
                    <Card className="hovercard">
                        <Row>
                            <CardColumns sm={6} lg={3}>a
                                <CardHeader>
                                    {this.props.homestay}
                                </CardHeader>
                                <CardText className="avatar">
                                    <img alt="profile img" src={this.props.profilePic}/>
                                </CardText>
                                <div className="info">
                                    <CardText>{this.props.descrip}</CardText>
                                </div>
                                <CardFooter>
                                    {this.props.price}
                                </CardFooter>
                            </CardColumns>
                        </Row>
                    </Card>
                </InfoWindow>
            </Marker>
        )
    }
}
```

You can see the code for yourself here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/93258nn8m4
I can't get the infowindow to come up - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order to control `InfoWindow` visibility, you have to render or not render `<InfoWindow />`, instead of passing `isOpen` as prop.

Here's how you should do it ([according to the official docs](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#infowindow)):

```
{ isOpen && <InfoWindow>
  <Card className="hovercard">
    <Row>
      <CardColumns sm={6} lg={3}>
        a
        <CardHeader>{this.props.homestay}</CardHeader>
        <CardText className="avatar">
          <img alt="profile img" src={this.props.profilePic} />
        </CardText>
        <div className="info">
          <CardText>{this.props.descrip}</CardText>
        </div>
        <CardFooter>{this.props.price}</CardFooter>
      </CardColumns>
    </Row>
  </Card>
</InfoWindow> }
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that invoking `setState` does not immediately change the state as stated [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), therefor, your `console.log`s right after it may not be accurate. If you need a working example, [check this out](https://codesandbox.io/s/jlmz8lkvo3)